# How to use regex (in JS) match words and include html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Amateur at JavaScript here. I set my self-projects to help myself learn. 
I usually find the answers on stackoverflow but several days of googling have not enlightened me on the following.
I’m trying to match whole words in sentences. I plan to do this to wrap the words in `<span>` tags.
The regex I’m using is

```
  (\/?+<?+\w+<?+>?+)
```

seen in use here http://regex101.com/r/nT2yY4

If this code is run on the string `this is a <span>string</span>` It returns

1. this
2. is
3. a
4. `<span>`
5. `string<`
6. `/span>`

I'd like it to return

1. this
2. is
3. a
4. `<span>string</span>`

while the string `<span>two words</span>` returns

1. `<span>two`
2. `words</span>`

also I'd like punctuation pulled split off as well so `"this is a string."` becomes

1. this
2. is
3. a
4. string
5. .

Comment: Someone is going to link to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: What I got from that post was don't use regex with html parsing. Can you offer suggestion of how I should do this in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex instead:

```
/([\w<>\/]+|\.)/g
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/rJ4rR8

Comment: Thanks! This gives me a great leg up!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like all you care about is the spaces and not the tags, so can't you just use something like:

```
/([^\W]+)/g
```

To split on whitespace.

If I test that on "This is a sentence with some words and also multiple words sometimes" then the result is, I think, what you've asked for.

Comment: I've added clarification to my post regarding punctuation. I want the punctuation split off separate to the words. Sorry. I should have mentioned this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `this is a <span>string</span>` to be split at white space, use:

```
"this is a <span>string</span>".split(" ");
```

which gives you:

```
[ 'this', 'is', 'a', '<span>string</span>' ]
```

Comment: Sorry. I should have put some punctuation in to demonstrate the problem with str.split(" "). `"this is a <span>string</span>.".split(" ");` I would want the "." to be split off as well.